# binary data shell echo generator

Tags: php, bash, security, escaping, binary

edit: here is a cleaned-up version incorporating most (but not all) feedback, thanks guys; https://gist.github.com/divinity76/79efd7b8c0d7849b956cd194659c98e5

edit2, 2021-07-16: found a bug (possible security vulnerability, even?), it will fail on echo -ne "-ne", that can fixed that by adding `$i !== 0 &&`  before `strpos($specialAsciiWhitelist, $curr)`

I need to... generate a linux shell command that prints binary data to stdout (which will then be piped to something's stdin, in this case it's actually curl),

The easy way to do it would be to just generate commands like `echo base64 | base64 -d` , but most often the data will be near-ascii (in fact it will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-data much of the time), and it would be beneficial for debugging if the generated command was readable (base64 isn't readable),

I made this generator:

```php
/**
 * generate command to echo (binary?) data to stdout
 *
 * @param string $binary
 *            the (optionally binary) data to echo
 * @param int $max_ish_line_length
 *            the circa-max line length for the data (PS! it's not accurate, it wraps at *circa* this length)
 * @return string
 */
function generateBinaryEcho(string $binary, int $max_ish_line_length = 50): string
{
    $inner_max_ish_line_length = (- 2) + $max_ish_line_length;
    $ret = "";
    // http://www.asciitable.com/
    $specialAsciiWhitelist = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
    $line_length = strlen("echo -ne '");
    $add = function (string $string_to_add) use (&$ret, &$line_length): void {
        $line_length += strlen($string_to_add);
        $ret .= $string_to_add;
    };
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($binary); ++ $i) {
        if ($line_length >= $inner_max_ish_line_length) {
            $ret .= "'\\\n'";
            $line_length = strlen("'");
        }
        $curr = $binary[$i];
        if ($curr === "\\") {
            $add("\\\\");
            continue;
        }
        if ($curr === '\'') {
            $add('\'\\\'\'');
            continue;
        }
        if ($curr === "\n") {
            $add("\\n");
            continue;
        }
        if ($curr === "\r") {
            $add("\\r");
            continue;
        }
        if (ctype_alnum($curr) || strpos($specialAsciiWhitelist, $curr) !== false) {
            $add($curr);
            continue;
        }
        // some binary-ish or unicode-ish data, hex-escape it..
        $hex = bin2hex($curr);
        $hex = str_split($hex, 2);
        $hex = '\\x' . implode('\\x', $hex);
        $add($hex);
        continue;
    }
    $ret = "echo -ne '" . $ret . "'";
    return $ret;
}
```

usage:

```
<?php
$everything = "";
for($i=0;$i<256;++$i){
    $everything.=chr($i);
}
$str = "Hello, World!" . $everything;
echo generateBinaryEcho($str);
```

outputs:

```sh
echo -ne 'Hello, World!\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06'\
'\x07\x08\x09\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13'\
'\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f'\
' !"#$%&'\''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJK'\
'LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy'\
'z{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89'\
'\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95'\
'\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1'\
'\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad'\
'\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9'\
'\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5'\
'\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1'\
'\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd'\
'\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9'\
'\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5'\
'\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

as for tests,

```
$everything = "";
for($i=0;$i<256;++$i){
    $everything.=chr($i);
}
echo generateBinaryEcho($everything);
```

outputs:

```
echo -ne '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09'\
'\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16'\
'\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&'\'''\
'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV'\
'WXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80'\
'\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c'\
'\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98'\
'\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4'\
'\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0'\
'\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc'\
'\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8'\
'\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4'\
'\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0'\
'\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec'\
'\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8'\
'\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

I'll call that output for "everything" from here on,

and when I run:

```
everything | wc -c
```

wc tells me it contains 256 bytes (as expected)

and when I run:

```
everything | hex
```

I get:

> 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabacadaeafb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9babbbcbdbebfc0c1c2c3c4c5c6c7c8c9cacbcccdcecfd0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9dadbdcdddedfe0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9eaebecedeeeff0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff

and when I cross-reference that with the original $everything variable from php, there's 0 corruption there, so it seems to work (related fun fact: in PHP, strings are just byte arrays)

(I know that allowing `|` and `\` and `'` without hex'ing it is kind of like playing with fire, but i think i managed to do it in a secure manner, it'd be impressive if someone proves me wrong though).

Comment: Instead of editing the question to update your code (and risking invalidation of answers), it's better to post your discovery as a self-answer.  We encourage you to point out as an answer what you missed when writing the code - more people will learn from it that way!  (and you'll gain more reputation points)

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the heads-up, i have reverted the code, but i left in the warning that the original code now has a known bug. i don't want to make a new answer, as i have very little to add besides Sam Onela's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Separating concerns, Simplifying code

The function has quite a bit going on. In every iteration of the `for` loop `$add` is called, so a separate function to get the character to add could be abstracted from within the loop. The series of `if` statements can be simplified by making a mapping of values to add - see `$replacements` in the sample below. Actually the function `$add` makes little sense- the loop can simply determine how many characters to add to `$line_length` and add the character to `$ret`.

The conditional block at the beginning of the loop could be eliminated if the characters were **mapped** to an array and the array was split into lines (e.g. using [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and `implode()`).

#### Initializing line length variable

The variable `$ret` could be initialized with the start of the string:

> ```
> $ret = "echo -ne '";
> ```

That way instead of setting the length using a hard-coded string that is repeated later on:

> ```
> $line_length = strlen("echo -ne '");
> ```

It can just reference that string:

```
$line_length = strlen($ret);
```

Obviously this would require updating the value returned from the function.

Also this line to reset the line length within the loop:

> ```
> $line_length = strlen("'");
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
$line_length = 1;
```

Though that is a micro-optimization, which PHP might already handle.

#### Iterating over the string

Instead of iterating over the string using a standard `for` loop, a `foreach` could be used with an array. There are multiple ways to generate an array -e.g. with [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/str_split) which will split the string into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#refsect1-function.str-split-notes)</sup>, or [`mb_split()`](https://www.php.net/mb_split).

```
foreach(str_split($binary) as $i => $curr) {
```

Then there is no need to set `$curr` manually in the loop:

```
$curr = $binary[$i];
```

#### Excess `continue`

There is a useless `continue` statement at the end of the `for` loop. While it doesn't have any affects it could lead to confusion by anyone reading the code (including your future self).

### Updated Code

I tested this code on [tehplayground.com](https://tehplayground.com/UDS4V5UNKe0anNXm)

```
function encodeChar($char) {
    //could be declared as a constant
     $replacements = [
        "\\" => "\\\\",
        '\'' => '\'\\\'\'',
        "\n" => "\\n",
        "\r" => "\\r"
    ];
    // http://www.asciitable.com/
    $specialAsciiWhitelist = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
    if (isset($replacements[$char])) {
        return $replacements[$char];
    }
    if (ctype_alnum($char) || strpos($specialAsciiWhitelist, $char) !== false) {
        return $char;
    }
    // some binary-ish or unicode-ish data, hex-escape it..
    $hex = bin2hex($char);
    $hex = str_split($hex, 2);
    return '\\x' . implode('\\x', $hex);
}
/**
 * generate command to echo (binary?) data to stdout
 *
 * @param string $binary
 *            the (optionally binary) data to echo
 * @param int $max_ish_line_length
 *            the circa-max line length for the data (PS! it's not accurate, it wraps at *circa* this length)
 * @return string
 */
function generateBinaryEcho(string $binary, int $max_ish_line_length = 50): string
{
    $inner_max_ish_line_length = (- 2) + $max_ish_line_length;
    $ret = "echo -ne '";
    $line_length = strlen($ret);
    foreach(str_split($binary) as $curr) {
        if ($line_length >= $inner_max_ish_line_length) {
            $ret .= "'\\\n'";
            $line_length = 1;//strlen("'");
        }
        $encodedChar = encodeChar($curr);
        $line_length += strlen($encodedChar);
        $ret .= $encodedChar;
    }
    return $ret . "'";
}
```

Comment: thanks for reviewing it! several good points, and i'm glad no actual bugs were found.  (this next part doesn't really matter, but the overhead of str_split() is much greater than what would be saved with the strlen() optimization, but php 7.1 added const strlen optimization anyway, strlen("'") compiles to int(1) as of php 7.1 ^^ also isset() is faster than array_key_exists, array_key_exists is a function call with function-call-overhead, isset() is an operator or something, isset doesn't have function-call-overhead. important to note that the 2 behaves differently, but only related to nulls)

Comment: found a bug (possible vulnerability?) that we both missed: `-` needs to be encoded if it is the very first character, because otherwise echo thinks its part of echo options instead of data-to-be-printed, a quickfix would be ```$encodedChar = ((strlen($ret) === 10 && $curr === '-' )? '\\x2d' : encodeChar($curr));``` - that's not a good fix, just a quickfix ^^ testcase: `echo generateBinaryEcho("-ne");`